# how to add back (older post) , next (newer post) and home buttons in the top of the page?

Tags: html

Hi I need help adding the Next (newer post), Back (older post) and Home buttons in the top of the page, but am having a hard time. I currently have them at the bottom/footer of the page, and they work well down there but not at the top.

Any help is much appreciated.

here is my site for reference: https://greatestguitars.blogspot.com

Thank you,
Carlos

Answer (score 0):

They cannot be created in plain HTML, as each post is going to have it's relative links different. You would have to somehow connect to the database and check the links of previous/next posts and then substitute the hrefs (urls). If you have access to Javascript you can also fetch the urls from the buttons at the bottom of the page.

Comment: How can fetch them with java script?

Comment: thank you I was able to do this with Javascript, it takes a bit, but works!!